# "Новая форма трюфеля". - нужны ли здесь кавычки и заглавная буква?

Tags: орфография

Новая форма трюфеля... (в смысле названия конфеты, которое в новой форме будет иметь другое название)- в данном контексте как правильно пишем "трюфеля" - с большой буквы и в кавычках?

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, по идее, кавычки не нужны. Например, как бы Вы написали "новая форма ирисок" или "новая форма леденцов"?..

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, что именно вы подразумеваете.

Если «Трюфель» — это официальное название конфеты (напр. «Мишка на севере»), то с большой и в кавычках.
Если трюфель — это просто название типа конфеты (напр. шоколадная конфета, ирис, леденец), то с маленькой и без кавычек.

Судя по вопросу, вам нужен второй вариант :)